# creating attractive buttons in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hii
I want attractive buttons for my website
how can i do that

Comment: What do you mean by "attractive"... examples?

Comment: I mean to say that
.. I want buttons like ok , submit, cancel,etc

..I want to show all buttons in my website..
but not in simple format.. I want some designs , some diff colors ,etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Liatro button maker http://www.bestshareware.net/liatro-button-maker.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could always draw them however you wanted in photoshop, save them for web, then use the ImageButton control where you wanted a custom button.  Just set the ImageURL property of the ImageButton control to the image you want to display.  You could even add some javascript to change the image when the mouse is over it and change back when it leaves.

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" ImageUrl="images/whatever.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/whateverOver.gif'" onmouseout="this.src='images/whatever.gif'"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, maybe you can give a try to [this](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Comment: jquery rocks.  That would be great to quickly theme the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [As Button Generator](http://jirox.net/AsButtonGen/). Great Web 2.0 buttons. It's an online flash program.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sliding doors technique and CSS, e.g. http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html